# C# resource file - how to access internal resources from XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources, internal

This is my simple (newbie) understanding: 
We have a choice for the Ressource Code Generator: *internal* or *public*. The default appears to be *internal*. I understand the resources are created with an internal or public accessor depending on that choice. 
Therefore, if the accessor is public I can use something like:

`Text="{x:Static resx:Resources.SomeLabelID}"`

... in my XAML. 
My question is either/both:

- What use is a generated *internal* accessor when the XAML shown above does not work (more precisely it 'works' in design mode but not at run time thus creating confusion for a newbie)? 
  *Note: There are **many** answers in SO that simply say to change the accessor to 'public' without explaining why, which I think would by nice to understand, especially since the default appears to be internal.*

-OR-

- Is there another way to access resource strings (from XAML) when the code is generated with the *internal* accessor ?

Thank you

Comment: Resource files are not wpf specific - you can use them in any type of application. They were available when WPF did not exist yet. They are internal by default for the same reason classes are internal be default or methods and fields are private by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything defined in `XAML` is using `internal` access modifier. That is by design of `WPF` framework, simply so you will not be able to access locally defined controls in different assembly.

Generally if you are going to use `strings` for "static" controls (i.e. `Label`) then you can simply go a head with changing access modifier.

Comment: "*Generally* if you are going to use strings for "static" controls (i.e. Labels) then you can simply go ahead and change the access modifier [from *private* to *public*]." ... that's exactly the answer I was looking for.